# Can a sizzle selector evaluate a regular expression?

Tags: regex, sizzle

I need to select links with a specific format of URLs.  **Can I use sizzle to evaluate a link's href attribute against a regular expression?**

For example, can I do something like this:

```
var arrayOfLinks = Sizzle('a[HREF=[0-9]+$]');
```

to create an array of all links on the page whose URL ends in a number?

Comment: I tried, but don't have enough time to figure out the api (doesn't look very documented). I don't think it supports in natively, but your can probably write a plugin, like on jQuery -  http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Comment: @Kobi.  Thanks for your time in taking a look at this.  Unfortunately, it's pretty unlikely that I'll be able to add jQuery and a plug-in in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. I've attempted to convert the jQuery regex selector that Kobi linked to into a Sizzle selector extension. Seems to work, but I haven't put it through a lot of testing.

```
Sizzle.selectors.filters.regex = function(elem, i, match){ 
    var matchParams = match[3].split(',', 2);
    var attr = matchParams[0];
    var pattern = matchParams[1];
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), 'ig');
    return regex.test(elem.getAttribute(attr));
};
```

In this case, your example would be written as:

```
var arrayOfLinks = Sizzle('a:regex(href,[0-9]+$)');
```

Comment: You should use `match[3].split(',', 2)`.

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks. Missed that when porting over the jQuery selector.

Comment: Cool solution. On a semi-related note, I wonder if there is a way to get the regexp results rather than the nodes. Maybe it could stuff it in the match object? Or in jQuery on the jQuery result?